# echo value to a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to have a PHP variable which value is generated by FBML.

I can do that by go back and forth through AJAX.

I wonder that it can be done purely in PHP.

This seems nonsense but what I want to do is like this. Just to show my idea.

```
$value = echo "<fb:comments-count href=$url></fb:comments-count>";
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ob_start();
echo "<fb:comments-count href=$url></fb:comments-count>";
$value = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean();
```

But it is still pointless. As long as you can perform `echo`, you could perform variable assigning also.

Comment: That <fb:comments-count> tag returns an integer. I want to take that integer value only. That's the point.

Comment: it seems facebook have to process these directives first. i think

Comment: @Jeong Woo Chang: it **works on client side**, so you'll not get the result anyway )))

Comment: Simply saving buffer misses my point. It should be parsed by Facebook API and then it should be saved as a PHP variable.

Comment: @Jeong Woo Chang: exactly. So start using FB PHP SDK (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comments_info/)

Comment: @zerkms I had used PHP SDK + Javascript SDK before the problem is using PHP SDK slows down so much my Web application. Using pure Javascript SDK solved the problem. Some logout issues are also problem with PHP SDK possibly due to new Oauth 2.0 adaptation in PHP SDK?

Comment: @Jeong Woo Chang: I haven't experienced any such issues. PS: not PHP SDK slows down your app, but requests to facebook do. And it can be solved with reducing amount of requests to reasonable minimum + caching layer.

Comment: @zerkms I think facebook trying to support less on other SDK but focusing more on Javascript SDK. Sounds weird though I have compared using those two and it gives different performance. Still does not make sense to me unless they intend to service their PHP SDK with less broadband and smaller servers than that of Javascript.

Comment: @Jeong Woo Chang: " I think facebook trying to support less on other SDK but focusing more on Javascript SDK" --- you're wrong here. Any server side SDK is pretty trivial piece of software, so you can write your own easily, it's not a big deal. "Still does not make sense to me unless they intend to service their PHP SDK with less broadband and smaller servers than that of Javascript." --- **WHAT?!** They serve it with the same absolutely the same API (thus the same servers)

Comment: @zerkms So you haven't had PHP SDK Logout problem? I have seen many people saying having problem with not able to logout through a logout link created by PHP SDK.

Comment: @Jeong Woo Chang: No, I haven't. Any links to FB bugtracker?

Comment: @zerkms I was using basically similar PHP code and it was too slow to use. ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648614/facebook-php-sdk-right-way

Comment: @Jeong Woo Chang: it is not possible. SDK class **doesn't perform any actions** itself. Probably you had something other than just an SDK there

Comment: @zerkms Yeah you were right I'm trying using PHP SDK now. It does not have any slowing problem now.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do what you want, other than wait until it is parsed client side and then send the variable value by ajax back to your server.

Comment: That sounds bad :( Reality is harsh

Comment: "and then send the variable value by ajax back to your server." --- non-trusted source is worse than no source at all.

Comment: That's the problem with programming, it's always about the reality even if the documentation says otherwise

Comment: @zerkms, Can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
ob_start();
echo $whatever;
$var = ob_get_clean();
```